# VS Code: How to format CSS in a more condensed way?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using [Beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) for formatting HTML and CSS in VSCode.

I would like to keep my CSS condensed like so:

```
h1  { margin:24px 0 0; font-size:20px; text-transform:capitalize; }
p   { margin-top:12px; }
a   { text-decoration:none; color:green; }
```

But, by default, Beautify inserts newlines to separate declarations and double-newlines between selectors:

```
h1 {
    margin: 24px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

p {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
}
```

Is there any way Beautify, or another CSS formatter, can be configured not to do that?